# Qt pixel manipulation in android is slow

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es, pixel, qimage

I am using Qt to show a video using images which are made using pixel manipulation.

I have a timer which signals every 1 milisecond which is initialized like this in my **MainWindow** constructor:

```
image = new QImage(w,h,QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
painter = new QPainter(image);
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tick()));
timer->start(1);
```

And whenever it calls `tick()` method, I draw something on **QImage** using **QPainter**. then I draw the image on window in **paintEvent** method using the code below:

```
QImage img = image->scaled(this->size(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation);
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, img);
this->setPalette(palette);
```

On Microsoft Windows I can get around 200 frames per second speed but on Android it is around 10 frames per second.

How can I speed it up on android?
How can I change it to OpenGL if it is faster?

Comment: **Profile** your code; **find** the bottlenecks; **optimize** them. Without knowing exactly what you're doing and the capabilities of the CPUs involved, I'm afraid I'll need a better crystal ball. Besides, what is the point at redrawing every millisecond, if your display can show only up to 60 images per second?

Comment: @peppe Well, I can only find QML profiler but my project is Widget not QML. Please tell me how to Profile my code in Qt Creator. Besides, The drawing time takes time. Forexample if the first draw at time 0 takes 100 milliseconds, the timer starts next draw at time 101. That is why I have 10 frames per second speed.